# Getting error while trying to read a file content from a json file

Tags: java, json

Ask: I am trying to capture the values captured inside key "value" and display it on console. However when executed getting error as"org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject"

Code Written:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class FileExtractJSON 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            try 
            {
                System.out.println("Reading JSON file from Java program");
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\shisyadav\\Desktop\\HP Remainco\\JSON Objects\\directkafkaconsumer_actual.json");
                JSONObject value_expected = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileReader);
                JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) value_expected.get("value"); 
                Iterator i = jsonObject.iterator();
                System.out.println("Values:");
                while (i.hasNext()) 
                {
                    System.out.println(""+i.next());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

[Sample file from which we are trying to capture value against key "value"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Kgz.jpg)

Comment: Since it is an array you need to store it as JSONArray and not JSONObject (after parsing)

Comment: new Gson().toJson(fileReader); use this hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your file has `JSONArray`, not `JSONObject`. Check your Json has `[]` at the begining.

[image]

```
JSONObject value_expected = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileReader);
```

So this line(top) should be this (below)

```
JSONArray value_expected = (JSONArray) parser.parse(fileReader);
```

Comment: I tried that as well. However, then it gives me same error when executed                                                                               
JSONArray value_expected = (JSONArray) parser.parse(fileReader);
JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) value_expected.get(0);

Comment: JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) value_expected.get(0);---This is the line giving error

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) value_expected.get(0); // try this, as it is a JSONObject

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) value_expected.get(0);//using this gives the same error as line above this code contains

JSONArray value_expected = (JSONArray) parser.parse(fileReader);